# The SharePoint site * is missing a target, task or history list

Tags: list, workflow, error

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm trying to create a new workflow with MS Visual Studio after creating a few lists, but when the wizard is asking me the name of the workflow, the following error message is shown:

**The SharePoint site at `http://jmoreno:10493/` is missing a target,
task, or history list. Each of these lists is required to associate a
workflow template. Please create a list and then launch this
wizard.**

Here you can see the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I have the following three lists:

[image]

And I would like to associate the workflow to the list "**Solicitud de viajes**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the lists required for workflows on your site before proceeding with Visual Studio.

To do that:

1. Ensure that a workflow feature is activated on your site collection (any workflow feature will do `http://yoursite/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site`)
2. Add a workflow to a list/library on your site by:

   - Browsing to a list/library on your site
   - Selecting "Workflow Settings" from the ribbon
   - Clicking "Add a workflow"
   - Configuring your workflow

This will create the lists required for workflows (as mentioned in your error message).